# NoMethodError - undefined method in routes following Railscast 145

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, activemerchant, railscasts, nomethoderror

I'm using Rails 3.1 and following [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/145-integrating-active-merchant) to implement active merchant, I'm  trying to copy the shopping cart used in the episode but am getting this error:

> NoMethodError
>
> undefined method `current_cart' for # Rails.root:
>   /users/dave/work/sell
>
> Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace config/routes.rb:7:in
>   `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>' config/routes.rb:6:in`block in
>   ' config/routes.rb:1:in `' This error
>   occurred while loading the following files:
>   /users/dave/work/sell/config/routes.rb

**My Routes.rb**

```
Sell::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :orders

  current_cart 'cart', :controller => 'carts', :action => 'show', :id => 'current'

  resources :line_items
  resources :carts    
  resources :products 
end
```

The rails cast version (from looking at the source on github) uses the |map| map.resources :whatever way of writing the routes.rb.

Thanks for any help its much appreciated!

Comment: Try change route like `get 'cart' => 'carts#show', :as => 'current_cart'`.

Comment: @taro, that works great, thanks very much, add as an answer and I'll tick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try change route like

```
get 'cart' => 'carts#show', :as => 'current_cart'
```